# Python Regex: Match paragraph numbers

Tags: python, regex

I am attempting to match paragraph numbers inside my block of text. Given the following sentence:

> Refer to paragraph C.2.1a.5 for examples.

I would like to match the word `C.2.1a.5`.

My current code like so:

```
([0-9a-zA-Z]{1,2}\.)
```

Only matches `C.2.1a.` and `es.`, which is not what I want. Is there a way to match the full `C.2.1a.5` and not match `es.`?

https://regex101.com/r/cO8lqs/13723

I have attempted to use `^` and `$`, but doing so returns no matches.

Comment: You should provide more examples of how can your paragraph look. It's not possible that anyone can help you make good regexp without knowing more.

Comment: The demo link you have provided has nothing to do with this question. Please provide more sample data so that the question can be answered properly.

Comment: Apologies, didn't realise I copied the wrong url. Edited url

Comment: Do you have any more examples of valid paragraph numbers? It's hard to design a regex without that.

Comment: will the paragraph numbers always be similar to `C.2.1a.5` in format ?

Comment: The pattern matches `es.` because it ends on matching a dot. You could prevent that by matching the character class and repeat that starting with a dot. Note that this matches the character class ranges and is a broad match for a paragraph number `\b[0-9a-zA-Z]{1,2}(?:\.[0-9a-zA-Z]{1,2})+\b` https://regex101.com/r/3KLC6h/1

Answer (score 2):

You should use following regex to match the paragraph numbers in your text.

```
\b(?:[0-9a-zA-Z]{1,2}\.)+[0-9a-zA-Z]\b
```

[Try this demo](https://regex101.com/r/cUd6Ep/1)

Here is the explanation,

- `\b` - Matches a word boundary hence avoiding matching partially in a large word like `examples.`
- `(?:[0-9a-zA-Z]{1,2}\.)+` - This matches an alphanumeric text with length one or two as you tried to match in your own regex.
- `[0-9a-zA-Z]` - Finally the match ends with one alphanumeric character at the end. In case you want it to match one or two alphanumeric characters at the end too, just add `{1,2}` after it
- `\b` - Matches a word boundary again to ensure it doesn't match partially in a large word.

**EDIT:**

As someone pointed out, in case your text has strings like `A.A.A.A.A.A.` or `A.A.A` or even `1.2` and you don't want to match these strings and only want to match strings that has exactly three dots within it, you should use following regex which is more specific in matching your paragraph numbers.

```
(?<!\.)\b(?:[0-9a-zA-Z]{1,2}\.){3}[0-9a-zA-Z]\b(?!\.)
```

This new regex matches only paragraph numbers having exactly three dots and those negative look ahead/behind ensures it doesn't match partially in large string like `A.A.A.A.A.A`

[Updated regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/cUd6Ep/2)

Check these python sample codes,

```
import re

s = 'Refer to paragraph C.2.1a.5 for examples. Refer to paragraph A.A.A.A.A.A.A for examples. Some more A.A.A or like 1.22'
print(re.findall(r'(?<!\.)\b(?:[0-9a-zA-Z]{1,2}\.){3}[0-9a-zA-Z]\b(?!\.)', s))
```

Output,

```
['C.2.1a.5']
```

Also for trying to use `^` and `$`, they are called start and end anchors respectively, and if you use them in your regex, then they will expect matching start of line and end of line which is not what you really intend to do hence you shouldn't be using them and like you already saw, using them won't work in this case.

Answer (score 1):

If simple version is required, you can use this easy to understand and modify regex `([A-Z]{1}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}[a-z]{1}\.[0-9]{1,3})`

Answer (score 0):

I think we should keep the regex expression simple and readable.
You can use the regex

```
**(?:[a-zA-Z]+\.){3}[a-zA-Z]+**
```

Explanation -

- The expression **(?:[a-zA-Z]+.){3}** ensures that the group **(?:[a-zA-Z]+.)** is to be repeated 3 times within the word. The group contains an alphabetic character followed a dot.
- The word would end with an alphabetic character.
  Output:
  ['C.2.1a.5']